# How to split the quantile results in 5 different data frames?

Tags: r, quantile

I'm running the `quantile` function in a dataframe and when I get the result of the quantile, I'd like to get those results in independent data frames to work with them separately, for example to add or subtract some of the quantile results to other values,etc.

Here a very simple example:

```
quantile(x <- rnorm(1001))

   0%          25%          50%          75%         100% 
  -2.930587810 -0.687108751  0.004405246  0.644589258  2.839597566
```

How Can I get the results in different data frames?

What I'd like to get is to subdivide quantile results in 5 independent results (data frames)
For example:

```
Q0<-2.9305878 Q1<-0.687108751 Q2<-0.00440524 Q3<-0.644589258  Q4<-2.839597566
```

Comment: maybe `lapply(quantile(rnorm(100)), data.frame)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I'd like is to have 5 diferent dataframes, one for each value. Q0,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4.  Any idea?

Comment: You can add or subract them while keeping them in a vector. e.g. `q <- quantile(x <- rnorm(1001)); 342 - q[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(quantile(x <- rnorm(1001))),paste0("Q",1:5)),.GlobalEnv)
```

Now you can write `Q1` and it will show up.

Comment: similar idea: `x<-rnorm(100);mapply(x = paste0('Q',1:5), y = quantile(x), FUN = function(x,y) assign(x,y, envir = .GlobalEnv))`